# Which statistical test to use in r when having different groups from different labs

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I have counts coming from 7 different groups.
Every of this count has been measured twice in two different labs.
I want to see if in general lab 1 and lab 2 have statistically different results.
This is my code in r:

```
n <- c(4858, 1492, 128, 136, 96, 0, 173, 4892, 1519, 94, 109, 95, 1, 60)
group <- factor(c("g1", "g2", "g3", "g4", "g5", "g6", "g7", "g1", "g2", "g3", "g4", "g5", "g6", "g7"))
lab <- factor(c("l1", "l1", "l1", "l1", "l1", "l1", "l1", "l2", "l2", "l2", "l2", "l2", "l2", "l2"))
df <- data.frame(n, group, lab)
```

This is what I have tried and what I get

```
res <- glm(n ~ group + lab, data = df)
summary(res)
Call:
glm(formula = n ~ group + lab, data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-332.6  -113.1     0.0   113.1   332.6  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   4760.9      209.4  22.735 4.74e-07 ***
groupg2      -3293.0      277.0 -11.887 2.15e-05 ***
groupg3      -4425.0      277.0 -15.973 3.82e-06 ***
groupg4      -4490.0      277.0 -16.208 3.51e-06 ***
groupg5      -4613.5      277.0 -16.654 2.99e-06 ***
groupg6      -4701.5      277.0 -16.971 2.68e-06 ***
groupg7      -4250.5      277.0 -15.343 4.84e-06 ***
labl2   -110.9      148.1  -0.749    0.482    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 76743.57)

    Null deviance: 34790719  on 13  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:   460461  on  6  degrees of freedom
AIC: 203.34

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

So basically I am applying a glm...
is this the right test to show that lab1 has significantly different results then lab2 (which is in my case not significant by the result of the pvalue in coefficient labl2 ?)?

Comment: You are not actually applying a GLM, because `glm` defaults to what is essentially Ordinary Least Squares--and that's not appropriate for these data, which include some relatively small counts.  What might matter even more is whether the counts in a given lab are truly independent.  For instance, if they were made by the same person on the same instrument; or if they are based on a common underlying sample, then they will include some non-independent sources of error that `glm` is incapable of modeling. You need to consider these issues before doing your analysis.

Comment: Is this the same example of my data, treated with glm?:


from Dobson (1990) Page 93: Randomized Controlled Trial :
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
print(d.AD <- data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts))
glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson())
anova(glm.D93)
summary(glm.D93)

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis above is also testing the difference between groups.
If you use boxplot(n ~ lab + group , data=df) one visual see both labs are similar. I would consider performing a sign test or matched pair t.test on the data. Does variability in the measurement differ from group1 to group 7? You may need to normalize the measurements based on the raw values.

```
#Exploratory analysis
boxplot(n ~ lab + group , data=df)
```

[image]

```
#ranked sign test - nonparametric test
wilcox.test(n ~ lab, data=df)

#check for normal difference
hist(df$n[1:7]- df$n[8:14], col="khaki")
#If deltas are approx normal, perform t-test
t.test(n ~ lab, data=df, paired=TRUE)
```

Comment: A closer inspection of the GLM residuals will show there *is* a difference between labs: they disagree substantially on group `g7`. One automatic way to see this is to use a more parsimonious model and plot the residuals, such as `library(lme4);
fit4 <- glmer(n ~ (1 | group) + lab, df, family="poisson");
plot(fit4)`

Comment: @whuber, I agree that group 7 does appear different.  I am not understanding the results from `glmer`. But could you explain how your test demonstrates that there is a significant difference between the lab considering the model does not show that the lab's coefficient as being significant.

Comment: I didn't conduct a formal test, but the very size of those two deviance residuals identifies them as outliers, which leads me to suppose that applying a decent goodness of fit test should detect the problem.